# Minimize the product of the traces of PSD matrices

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace

Given two positive semidefinite matrices, $X$ and $Y$, I want to minimize the product $\operatorname{Tr} (X) \operatorname{Tr} (Y)$.

Now as far as I understand the following holds:

1. $\operatorname{Tr} (X) \operatorname{Tr} (Y)$ is convex since $\operatorname{Tr} (X)$ and $\operatorname{Tr} (Y)$ are both convex (actually affine), positive and non-decreasing.
2. It cannot be done in CVX, since the DCP ruleset "...generally forbid products between nonconstant expressions, with the exception of scalar quadratic forms".

Is this two statements true? If so can I minimize $\operatorname{Tr} (X) \operatorname{Tr} (Y)$ with other convex optimiztion programs?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case when you have scalars. The product $xy$ is not convex (study the Hessian, or simply look at the definition of convexity using the two points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$)

More generally, it appears you think the products of two convex positive non-decreasing functions is convex. This is false. If memory serves me right, a *necessary* condition for the product $f(x)g(y)$ to be convex is that the two functions are log-convex.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've had people insist that $xy$ is convex if $x,y\geq 0$. I really don't know where this comes from. There seems to be a fount of incorrect convexity rules out there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I got the idea that (1) is true from Boyd's book (but maybe I understood wrong) Ex 3.32 p119: "If f and g are convex, both nondecreasing (or nonincreasing), and positive functions
on an interval, then fg is convex." Is this wrong or does not apply to my case?

Comment: I just realized the the problem with my case is that $Tr(X)$ is not non-decreasing. As far as I understand if $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are non-decreasing (in addition to  convex and positive) then $f(x)g(y)$ is convex (this is not the case for $xy$). Thanks!

Comment: @YairForchevsky, that exercise applies only to univariate functions *of the same variable*. So no, it doesn't work for $f(x)g(y)$. It only works for $f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: @YairForchevsky and in fact, $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X)$ *is* nondecreasing (and nonincreasing). That's not the issue.

Comment: OK, you're right. Thanks.